# NextJS dynamic routing, is "as" really necessary?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, dynamic-url, next-link

Both links work exactly the same, do we really need to use the `as`, can't we use just the `href`?

```
import Link from 'next/link'

export default function () {
  return (<>
    <Link href="/someroute">
      <a>WithOUT as</a>
    </Link>

    <br />
    <br />

    <Link href="/[param]" as="/someroute">
      <a>With as</a>
    </Link>
  </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"as" is used to have a nicer url. for example, since you are in a dynamic route, that `param` can be something very crazy, maybe a mongodb id or any hash value

```
 // mongodb id
 /507f191e810c19729de860ea

 // maybe ipfs hash
 /mtwirsqawjuoloq2gvtyug2tc3jbf5htm2zeo4rsknfiv3fdp46a
```

From [early docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/tag/v9.5.2/api-reference/next/link#dynamic-routes)

> `href` is a file system path used by the page and it shouldn't change at
> runtime. `as` on the other hand, will be dynamic most of the time
> according to your needs.

So when next.js navigates, to decide which page to render, it will look at the `href` but to decide which url to show the user, it will look at the `as`

## when "as" is helpful

Let's say you have a `DynamicPostComponent` and you are passing `post` prop

```
 const DynamicPostComponent = ({post}) => {}
```

Inside this component, you would tell next.js where to go in pages directory. so you use `href`

```
  // assume we have "pages/posts/[slug]" directory
  href="/posts/[slug]"
```

now inside the page you need to read the `id` of blog so that you have to fetch the post to show the user. for this you use `as`

```
 as={`/posts/${post.slug}`
```

Your Link compnent will look like this

```
 <Link href="/postss/[slug]" as={`/posts/${post.slug}`}>
    <a>
     
    </a>
  </Link>
```

`as` is removed after v10. https://nextjs.org/blog/next-10

> **Automatic Resolving of href:** The as property is no longer needed on next/link

Comment: Hello Yilmaz, thanks for your answer, but I was not able to reproduce that behavaiour: https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-y3edah?file=pages/[param].js  i tried 3 different ways, all the same result, you can click on upper right Open in new Tab to see the URL changing

Comment: I got your point. I updated the answer

Comment: I think i am starting to understand, is there a way to use the crazy ID? it seems that it's just being lost, because router.query always return `{"param":"someroute"}`

Comment: @PauloFernando next.js will read the "as"

Comment: @PauloFernando I edited the answer to be more descriptive

Comment: Yilmaz, would you example be like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nextjs-y3edah?file=pages/index.js)? It seems that you can just use the href, without the as. I even changed the name of the file for [slugX] and stills work. What i see is that if you use as, next will ignore the href and use the as, so why don't just put the route in the href?

Comment: @PauloFernando as is no longer is used. That is why I mentioned early docs. i think after version 10 removed.

Comment: sorry,  I should have mentioned it,  i was watching the world cup, https://nextjs.org/blog/next-10